# Answer multiple choice questions

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language

`FindTextualAnswer` isn't working for me here:

```
txt = CloudImport@CloudObject[
   "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/49966c6e-6c9e-4a3e-ba29-b58707ef35ba"];
AbsoluteTiming @ FindTextualAnswer[txt, "AI is finally possible because of?"]
```

[image]

If you ask for the top n most-likely answers, sometimes you get something more reasonable:

[image]

**What I really need is a probability over these options:**

[image]

Is there some-work around here to make this work - perhaps comparing embedding distances to each of the answers? Or perhaps someone knows of a multiple choice question-answer networks available in MMA to play with or train?

Comment: I think comparing embedding distances is a very sensible start. If you want to do something more sophisticated [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.02253v1.pdf) seems like a good place to begin.

Answer (score 2):

```
txt = CloudImport@
   CloudObject[
    "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/49966c6e-6c9e-4a3e-ba29-\
b58707ef35ba"];

choices = {"Big data, Turing test, recommendation test", 
   "Big data, smarter data models, powerful cloud computing", 
   "Cloud computing, general problem solver, paradigm shift", 
   "Big data, mainframe systems, the cloud"};
```

Simplistically selecting the choice with the largest number of string matches.

```
SortBy[Transpose@{choices,
    Length@
       StringCases[txt, 
        Alternatives @@
         StringSplit[StringReplace[#, ", " -> ","], ","],
        IgnoreCase -> True] & /@ choices}, Last][[-1, 1]]

(* "Cloud computing, general problem solver, paradigm shift" *)
```

Answer (score 0):

With

```
txt = CloudImport@
   CloudObject[
    "https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/49966c6e-6c9e-4a3e-ba29-\
b58707ef35ba"];
AbsoluteTiming@
 FindTextualAnswer[txt, 
  "Artificial Intelligence is finally possible because of?"]
```

you will get a very interesting answer.

Comment: I am looking for the likelihood of A, B, C, or D

Comment: Then you need to change the question. In this formulation, the answer is also funny.